# Generating public and private keys and reconciling shared keys based on Diffie Hellman

Tags: c++, crypto++

I have a problem in generating common private and public keys for 2 users Bob Alice based on common values using and encrypting data based on these keys c++ library cryptocpp.
Thank you for all your advice and comments

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cryptopp/cryptlib.h>
#include <cryptopp/dh.h>
#include <cryptopp/dh2.h>
#include <cryptopp/osrng.h>
#include <cryptopp/integer.h>
#include <cryptopp/nbtheory.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <hex.h>
using namespace std;
/*
using CryptoPP::RSA;
using CryptoPP::InvertibleRSAFunction;
using CryptoPP::RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor;
using CryptoPP::RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Decryptor;
*/
#include <rsa.h>

#include <modes.h>
using CryptoPP::CFB_Mode;

CryptoPP::Integer my_pow(CryptoPP::Integer base, CryptoPP::Integer exponent) 
{

    if (exponent == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (exponent == 1) {
        return base;
    }
    else
    {
        CryptoPP::Integer n = exponent / 2;
        CryptoPP::Integer xn2 = my_pow(base, n);

        if (exponent % 2 == 0) {
      return xn2 * xn2;
        }
        else {
      return xn2 * base;
        }
    }
}


CryptoPP::Integer power(CryptoPP::Integer a, CryptoPP::Integer b, CryptoPP::Integer P)
{
    if (b == 1)
        return a;
    else
        return (((CryptoPP::Integer)my_pow(a, b)) % P);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << std::hex;
    
    //All User ALICE BOB CryptoPP::Integer p, q,
    CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool rnd;
    CryptoPP::PrimeAndGenerator pg;
    pg.Generate(1, rnd, 512, 511);
    const CryptoPP::Integer p = pg.Prime();
    const CryptoPP::Integer q = pg.SubPrime();

    std::cout << "p" << p << endl;
    std::cout << "q" << q << endl;


    // Alice
    CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool prngA;
    CryptoPP::PrimeAndGenerator pgA;
    pgA.Generate(1, prngA, 512, 511);
    CryptoPP::Integer a = pgA.Generator();;
    // Bob
    CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool prngB;
    CryptoPP::PrimeAndGenerator pgB;
    pgB.Generate(1, prngB, 512, 511);
    CryptoPP::Integer b = pgB.Generator();;
    
    //Public aPublic = power(q, a, P);
    CryptoPP::Integer aPublic = power(q, a, p);
    
    //Public bPublic = power(q, a, P);
    CryptoPP::Integer bPublic = power(q, b, p);
    
    std::cout << "A Alice Key"; 
    std::cout << a << endl;
    std::cout << "B Bob Key";
    std::cout << b << endl;

    
    //Alice 
    CryptoPP::Integer kb = power(bPublic, a, p); // Secret key for Bob
   
    //Bob
    CryptoPP::Integer ka = power(aPublic, b, p); // Secret key for Alice

    std::cout <<"Bob Key" << kb << endl;
    std::cout <<"Alice Key" << ka << endl;
    if (kb == ka)
        std::cout << "Same"<<"\n";
    //Alice 
    CryptoPP::DH dhA = CryptoPP::DH(p, q, kb);
    CryptoPP::SecByteBlock t1A(dhA.PrivateKeyLength()), t2A(dhA.PublicKeyLength());
    dhA.GenerateKeyPair(rnd, t1A, t2A);
    std::cout << "Private Key" << t1A << "\n" << "Public Key" << t2A << "\n";

    //Bob
    CryptoPP::DH dhB = CryptoPP::DH(p, q, ka);
    CryptoPP::SecByteBlock t1B(dhB.PrivateKeyLength()), t2B(dhB.PublicKeyLength());
    dhB.GenerateKeyPair(rnd, t1B, t2B);
    std::cout << "Private Key" << t1B << "\n" << "Public Key" << t2B << "\n";


    return true;
}
```

Doesn't understand why different public and private keys are generated despite the same values.

Comment: To generate the same private keys for both Alice and Bob, you need to use the same random number generator.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same random number generator for both A and B.

```
// Common random number generator
CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool rnd;

// Alice
CryptoPP::PrimeAndGenerator pgA;
pgA.Generate(1, rnd, 512, 511);
CryptoPP::Integer a = pgA.Generator();

// Bob
CryptoPP::PrimeAndGenerator pgB;
pgB.Generate(1, rnd, 512, 511);
CryptoPP::Integer b = pgB.Generator();
```

Comment: I changed as you said the code in selected places 
and I added the code to check 
    if (t1A == t1B && t2A == t2B)
    {
        std::cout << "Same Key" << "}
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "No Same Key" << "\n";
    }
I changed as you said the code in selected places 
 and I added the code to check 
and so it generates me different public and private keys